# Wordpress - Contributors can't edit taxonomies. How to let them to do that

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site (v3.9.2) where contributors add/edit custom posts. These posts have custom fields and taxonomies. When a contributor add a custom post everything is OK, he can add the title, the content, custom fields and taxonomies. But when he try to edit a post which he added before and which was revised by a revisor, he is not able to edit the taxonomies because they aren't displayed. He can edit the title, the content and the custom fields but not the taxonomies.

Any idea or solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically define what certain user roles can and can't do.

```
// get the "author" role object
$role = get_role( 'author' );

// add "organize_gallery" to this role object
$role->add_cap( 'organize_gallery' );
```

Source: http://solislab.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/#add-capability (brilliant resource to user management in Wordpress)